# Most efficient way to write to response body in .NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1, c#-8.0

Is there a more efficient way to write to the response body in .NET Core 3.1?

I understand that the RequestDelegate for the Endpoint needs to be a Task as it will be launched as a thread by the .NET pipeline, but repetitive calls to WriteAsync using await seems overly verbose and inefficient.

Below is some sample code of what I'm trying to accomplish.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace Flux
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapGet("/", DefaultRequest);
            });
        }

        public async Task DefaultRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("<html>");
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("<head>");
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("<title>Hello World!</title>");
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("</head>");
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("<body>");
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("</body>");
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("</html>");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you build up the string using something like a `StringBuilder` and then make one call to `WriteAsync`?

Comment: I can, but its more a question of understanding if there's a better way to interface with the response body. For example, I know there's the `BodyWriter` property, but I'm not sure if that's more or less efficient then `WriteAsync`.

Comment: There are some measurements here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33940903/5045688

Comment: Alexander, that's exactly the information I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [answer given by Rick Love](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33940903/multiple-response-writeasync-calls), the `StringBuilder` approach is slower than a synchronous `Response.Write`, but it is a significantly faster method than the `Response.WriteAsync` one.

Comment: "```StringBuilder``` approach is slower than a synchronous ```Response.Write```". Really??

Comment: @HadiSamadzad really, and it's not hard to see why - `Write` sends data to the caller directly, even partial data, without using any extra memory while StringBuilder has to construct the entire response, essentially caching it, before it can be sent with ... `Write`. For large responses, this can seriously degrade scaleability *and* lead to GC overhead. Of course, with large responses avoiding blocking operations with `WriteAsync` is far more important than the async overhead

Comment: @HadiSamadzad if you wanted to send a large CSV to the client, you could use `Write` to send it line-by line. With StringBuilder you'd have to construct the entire file in memory (allocating in the LOH) before sending it to the client

Answer (score 1):

it looks like what you are looking for is to inject a static html file. There is a Tutorial here you can use: [Click Me](https://www.talkingdotnet.com/make-index-html-startup-file-in-aspnet-core/)

That way you can simply write your html file, and then inject it, so you don't have to do it line by line. :

Comment: Not at all, I only added some static HTML as an example.